# django server push at specific times

Tags: python, django, push, clients

I want to create a page in which I can "push" data to clients, on specific times in day.
What are my options?  I know there is socket.io, which is javascript based, but I need it to work with django. Also, I need to push the events to clients based on the server time.

EDIT:
I mean to something like this:
in javascript:

```
listener.onserverpush(function(data) {...});
```

the server push should occur in server at specific hours in a day (based on server clock).

Comment: Push how? Email? Data refresh on a webpage? Something else?

Comment: "push" means a way that the client does not need to send a request to the server in order to get data from server. Usually I do an ajax request every few seconds, but here I want a way to push data to clients from django. something like what socket.io does, only that I need it on specific times in a day.